# Speck algorithm not working

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, cryptography, block-cipher

I am trying to implement **Speck 64bit block / 128bit key** cipher in java. I'm stuck at encryption / decryption algorithm. My decryption algorithm can't decrypt cipher text properly.

My implementation:

- Encryption:

  ```
  int m = 4; //key words
  int T = 27; //rounds
  int alpha = 8; //alpha
  int beta = 3; //beta
  int x,y;
  int[] l = new int[2*T], k = new int[T];
  /* *************** KEY EXTENSTION ***************** */
  for(int i = 0; i < T-1; i++) {
      l[i+m-1] = (k[i] + rotateRight(l[i], alpha)) ^ i;
      k[i+1] = rotateLeft(k[i], beta) ^ l[i+m-1]; 
      //System.out.println(k[i]);
  }
  /* *************** ENCRYPTION ********************* */
  for(int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
      x = (rotateLeft(x, alpha) + y) ^ k[i];
      y = rotateRight(y, beta) ^ x;
      //System.out.println(y);
  }
  ```
- Decryption:

  ```
  /* *************** KEY EXTENSTION ***************** */
  for(int i = 0; i < T-1; i++) {
      l[i+m-1] = (k[i] + rotateRight(l[i], alpha)) ^ i;
      k[i+1] = rotateLeft(k[i], beta) ^ l[i+m-1];
      //System.out.println(k[i]);
  }
  /* *************** DECRYPTION ********************* */         
  for(int i = T-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      y = rotateRight(y, beta) ^ x;
      x = (rotateLeft(x, alpha) - y) ^ k[i];
      //System.out.println(y);
  }
  ```

**x** and **y** are initialized by function boxing(<- little bit weird):

```
    x = boxing(plainText, 0, 1);
    y = boxing(plainText, 1, 2);

public static int boxing(int[] content, int i, int count) {
    int temp[] = new int[count];
        temp[i] |= content[i*4] & 0xff;
        temp[i] = temp[i] << 8 | content[i*4+1] & 0xff;
        temp[i] = temp[i] << 8 | content[i*4+2] & 0xff;
        temp[i] = temp[i] << 8 | content[i*4+3] & 0xff;
        //System.out.println(temp[from]);

    return temp[i];
}
```

Note that **content** is int array of 8 characters.

I put decryption right behind encryption, so I could see if this algorithm is really working, but it isn't and I don't know why. (I reset variables to their proper values, before I used decryption).

**References**

- The SIMON and SPECK Families of Lightweight Block Ciphers
  https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/404
- Speck implementation (not mine) 
  https://github.com/timw/bc-java/blob/feature/simon-speck/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/engines/SpeckEngine.java

EDIT:

- Rotate functions:

  ```
  public static int rotateLeft(int number, int amount) {
     return number << amount | number >>> (32-amount);
  }
  public static int rotateRight(int number, int amount) {
     return number >>> amount | number << (32-amount);
  }
  ```

Comment: There are test vectors at the end of the paper in appendix C. How about you first check that encryption works and then check decryption.

Comment: It seems everything is pretty straightforward, except for the rotate functions, which are missing.

Comment: Added rotate functions. But mine rotate functions are working at two other ciphers. XTEA and RC5, so I think they're good.

Comment: @Amphoru - Are you able to validate the algorithm using the SPECK test   vector? I'm pretty sure the test vectors are wrong (or the authors of the paper omitted necessary information). I modified their reference implementation to operate the cipher in ECB mode and it could not arrive at the test vector result.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - If you get some time would you take a look at [Noloader | Simon-and-Speck](https://github.com/noloader/Simon-and-Speck). I've spent two days trying to arrive at the published test vector results and I can't seem to do it. The GitHub adds a `main` to the SuperCop reference implementation, and it can't arrive at the test vector results either.

Comment: @jww The test vectors are not wrong but they seem to be given given in big-endian form. The endianness of how input blocks and keys are converted to the two words is not specified in the original document. The authors have commented, that they intended little-endian interpretation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speck_(cipher)#Endianness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out. My **decryption** algorithm should look like this:

```
    for(int i = T-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        y = rotateRight(x ^ y, beta);
        x = rotateLeft((x ^ k[i]) - y, alpha);
    }
```

And I accidently swap *rotate functions* in **encryption** algorithm. This is correct form:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
        x = (rotateRight(x, alpha) + y) ^ k[i];
        y = rotateLeft(y, beta) ^ x;
    }
```